# Speeding up (startup of) Google Web Engine application

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, servlets

I maintain a website that contains output from a Google App Engine application inside an `iframe`. When a user visits that page, it takes more than 10 seconds for the content to be rendered.

Since the application logic is fairly trivial (report some values from a datastore that are obtained via Objectify) I assume the reason is that each visit may lead to a new startup of a new instance of my application somewhere in Google's cloud. Mine is currently a free GAE application.

Is there a good way to speedup such user-facing GAE applications by having them pre-loaded or otherwise? And what tools would allow my to find out what causes the observed multi-seconds delay in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this what "[Warmup Requests](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances#Warmup_Requests)" are for.